# Google Places Api in Turkey

Tags: google-places-api

Can i use google places api in Turkey ?

Because when I send the parameters,i take zero results

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please provide an example query and/or some code so I can help you troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're typing the parameters (and they're not sent dynamically) try another country. If you still take zero results you're doing something wrong.

Comment: When I am trying another country,ı can take result just I can t from Turkey